# How to convert NSString into hexDecimal value

Tags: objective-c

I have following line of code and I want to convert into `HexDecimal` value.

```
NSString *hexDecimal = @"&#x20ac;";
```

I want the result to be `hexDecimalValue = 0x20ac`.

Answer (score 0):

NSScanner can do this. Here an example method:

```
- (NSNumber *)scanHex:(NSString *)aString {

    NSScanner   *sc=[NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];

    if(![sc scanString:@"&#x" intoString:NULL]) return nil;

    unsigned long long  val;

    if(![sc scanHexLongLong:&val]) return nil;

    return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:val];
}
```

This method will return `nil` if `aString` does not have the `&#x` you list, or if that is not followed by a valid hex string. Otherwise it returns a NSNumber object with the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have HTML/XML escaped entities. What you really want to use is the Core Foundation function CFStringTransform. 
For that you'll want to have an NSMutableString and bridge it to CFMutableString.

The secret sauce is that this CF function wraps the ICU (International Components for Unicode) library's string transform.

The ICU docs will give you more possible transforms. But for this, you want Hex-Any as your transform if I recall correctly.